# Creating Nuget package in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I need to create a nuget package for xamrin.It should work for pcl projects.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating NuGet packages is relatively easy.

Just take a loot at [Micosofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) ([Create Corss-Platform Packages for Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin)) on creating NuGet packages. But short answer you can create them automated from .sln projects or you can create your own .nuspec package definition. It is easy to do for .NET-Projects but hard to if you want to create a native (C/C++) package.

It was also helfull for me to download some packages and taking a look at there structure. You can open downloaded packages with an Zip-Application like 7-Zip.

Comment: thank you.I didn't want to create a native package.I tried as you mentioned by create own .nuspec package.But when I add the files tag it gives errors in cmd

Comment: @Nayani this normally a sign of a syntax error of some sort. Try to confirm your xml file and many look again at the documentation.